# Canon LBP7110CW Won't work after "Upgrade" to 18.04

Tags: canon

Canon LBP7110CW Won't work after "Upgrade" to 18.04.  It installs as a text only printer.  It worked in whatever the previous version of Ubuntu was.  I am not a programmer or Techie, I'm an user. For the past 15 or 20 years Ubuntu has been good to me. However this problem is very Irritating. I've down loaded linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_usen.tar.gz from Canon to no avail. If some one could fix this issue I'd appreciate it. I am capable of copying and pasting terminal commands.

Comment: I am suffering too.  I followed the instructions precisely, and the libraries for 64-bit Ubuntu can't be installed.

Comment: I fumbled around with this today.  So, I opened the file folder "linux-UFRIILT-drv-v150-uken", open "64-bit_Driver" and then open "Debian" and double click on each of the three files there.  This should install each of them individually.  I re-ran the "./install.sh" (which I don't think affected my outcome.  But then was able to print to my Canon LBP7110cw on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Thanks Kirk, This worked. I had been trying it with V1.40 did not know about V1.5 until you posted it.  Thanks again...!!

Comment: I really wish I understood why it worked.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

I fumbled around with this today. So, I opened the file folder "linux-UFRIILT-drv-v150-uken", open "64-bit_Driver" and then open "Debian" and double click on each of the three files there. This should install each of them individually. I re-ran the "./install.sh" (which I don't think affected my outcome. But then was able to print to my Canon LBP7110cw on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS